# Roxy Fileman with CKEditor doesn't work after upload to server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor

I have to use any file manager on my website. I chose Roxy Fileman, because it is compatible with CKEditor, which is my main text editor. The problem is, everything works when i test it on my localhost, but after publishing it on server I get error message: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." There's no more info... Have you guys any idea what I should do?

Comment: Have you checked the directory permissions on your server for read/write access?

Comment: Of course I did it. Finally I removed it from my project, because I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @dzeju555, How did you solve this problem as i am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

1) make sure Fileman folder is added to the directory

2) go to Fileman folder and in web.config add below code into the staticContent tag

```
  <!--Cache static content for 24 hours-->
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="24.00:00:00" />
  <!--Allow json file loading (used by Roxy Fileman)-->
  <remove fileExtension=".json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
```

3) and finaly make sure Fileman has permission to write data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and after much research and diagnosing, this worked for me.

In the fileman directory, there is a web.config file. Open it in your text editor and you will  see the following line:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
</staticContent>
```

Delete it from the web.config and save. It is conflicting with something on the live server where this configuration is already being set. I hope this helps anyone.