# Can't get Roxy Fileman working on TinyMCE 4.x

Tags: json, iis, roxy-fileman

I'm trying to add [Roxy Fileman](http://www.roxyfileman.com/) to my project.

It works fine while debugging using localhost (meaning I can see the folders and manage them), but it doesn't work when I try to access it from the browser.

My project is on IIS 7. I tried to change the path in the file conf.json like this:

"FILES_ROOT":        "C:\SRV-XX\MyProject\Docs",

but I get this error: "error loading asp_net/main.ashx".

I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547659/roxy-fileman-with-ckeditor-doesnt-work-after-upload-to-server) so I tried to remove this code from the web.config inside the fileman folder:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
</staticContent>
```

but still nothing, I only get these alerts (E_LoadingConf and E_ActionDisables) and I'm not able to see the folders.

I also read [this article](http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/#.VDUiFIVsCvh) to make IIS handle*.jon files but it won't work either.

I don't really know how to fix this...please help me..this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I'm actually using asp .net framework 4.0.

I noticed that in my fileman/web.config I had these 3 code lines:

```
<assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
</assemblies>
```

I commented them and it worked! That assembly only works from framework 4.5.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

this error is about file permission on iis_user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permission to uploading folder

1. Right click on folder and then properties
2. under security tab, click on edit button
3. click on add button
4. in the box, type 'IIS/IUSRS' the press 'Check Names' button
5. click on OK and in the 'Permissions for IIS_IUSRS' section, check all Allow checkboxes to give permission to this folder.